# Web Services - Getting JSONException while handling request from External System

Tags: integration, webservices, apex-webservice

I have a JSON string like -

```
String jsonInput = '{"merch" : ['+
'{"name" : "Eraser1", "description" : "desc", "price" : 2},'+
'{"name" : "Eraser2", "description" : "desc", "price" : 204323423423412324333},'+
'{"name" : "Eraser3", "description" : "desc", "price" : 28}'+
']}';
```

I am deserializing the above string as shown below -

```
Map<String, Object> desMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonInput);
```

While deserializing I am getting error - ' System.JSONException: For input string: "204323423423412324333" '.

Now, when I am deserializing the below JSON string(by reducing price parameter length), it worked fine.

```
String jsonInput = '{"merch" : ['+
'{"name" : "Eraser1", "description" : "desc", "price" : 2},'+
'{"name" : "Eraser2", "description" : "desc", "price" : 204323423423412324},'+
'{"name" : "Eraser3", "description" : "desc", "price" : 28}'+
']}';

Map<String, Object> desMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonInput);
```

By seeing this I can conclude that it is length of the price parameter which is casuing JSONException in 1st case.

Can anyone help me with more explanation of the above scenario and how can I handle it.

Comment: JSON schema spec supports integers up to 2^53 = `9007199254740991` - perhaps you need to chat with the system owners of the supplier system

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Salesforce supports max up to 18 digit number, including decimal points. Even, in a real-time scenario, you won't need any number which is 21 digit `see 21 digits ---> (204323423423412324333)`.

> As of now, no such thing exists with a price of 21 digits integer in this world.
>   So it does make sense that why SF limits it up to 18.

If you still want to store that number, you can store it as a string

> (Again I am not sure how you are going to perform some calculations[if
>   any] on this number).

Refer [Primitive Data Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm)